# KOMA: Chapter & Header Styling (Uppercase + Chapterprexif)

Tags: header-footer, chapters, koma-script

Is there a way in KOMA-Script (or a workaround/package) to have the chaptername in **uppercase** and the chapterprefix in **smallcase** and the header of the next page without the prefix such as shown in the following picture?

**Desired Output:**
[image]

**At the moment I got this far:**

```
\documentclass[
     paper = a4,
     twoside = false,
     numbers = noenddot,  
     parskip = half,
     listof = flat,
     listof = entryprefix,
     chapterprefix = true,
     listof = nochaptergap]{scrreprt}

\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%Chapter name indentation
  \makebox[1.15cm][l]{\thechapter\autodot}%
}
\makeatletter %Uppercase chapter name
\renewcommand\chapterlinesformat[3]{%
  \@hangfrom{#2}{\MakeUppercase{#3}}%
}
\makeatother
\renewcommand*{\sectionformat}{%
  \makebox[1.15cm][l]{\thesection\autodot}%
}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionformat}{%
  \makebox[1.15cm][l]{\thesubsection\autodot}%
}  

% ============================================
% HEADER & FOOTER
% ============================================
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
     \clearpairofpagestyles
     \ohead{\MakeUppercase{\headmark}} %Chapter name in header
     \ofoot*{\pagemark} %Page number
     \setkomafont{pagehead}{\sffamily\bfseries\upshape}
     \setkomafont{pagenumber}{\sffamily\bfseries\upshape}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Section}
\newpage
Lorem ipsum
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have set option `chapterprefix=true`, so you have to redefine `\chapterlineswithprefixformat`:

```
\renewcommand*\chapterlineswithprefixformat[3]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{chapter}
    {#2\MakeUppercase{#3}}% changed definition for chapter
    {#2#3}% original definition for other levels with style=chapter
}
```

To get the chapter heading right aligned redefine `\raggedchapter` to `\raggedleft`:

```
\renewcommand*\raggedchapter{\raggedleft}% <- chapter alignment
```

`\chaptermarkformat` can simple be redefined to remove the chapter name:

```
\renewcommand*\chaptermarkformat{\thechapter\autodot\enskip}% for header
```

Note there is a option `markcase=upper` to set left and right marks with uppercase:

```
\usepackage[
  automark,
  markcase=upper% <- uppercase for left and right marks
]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\ohead{\headmark}% <- changed
```

Example:

```
\documentclass[
  paper = a4,
  twoside = false,
  numbers = noenddot,  
  parskip = half,
  listof = flat,
  listof = entryprefix,
  chapterprefix = true,
  listof = nochaptergap
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% <- added

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  innerskip=0pt,% skip between chapter prefix and chapter title
  prefixfont=\LARGE% font of chapter prefix
]{chapter}
\renewcommand*\raggedchapter{\raggedleft}% <- chapter alignment
\renewcommand*\chapterlineswithprefixformat[3]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{chapter}
    {#2\MakeUppercase{#3}}% changed definition for chapter
    {#2#3}% original definition for other levels with style=chapter
}
\renewcommand*\chaptermarkformat{\thechapter\autodot\enskip}% for header

\renewcommand*{\sectionformat}{%
  \makebox[1.15cm][l]{\thesection\autodot}%
}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionformat}{%
  \makebox[1.15cm][l]{\thesubsection\autodot}%
}  

% ============================================
% HEADER & FOOTER
% ============================================
\usepackage[
  automark,
  markcase=upper% <- uppercase for left and right marks
]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead{\headmark}% <- changed
\ofoot*{\pagemark}
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\sffamily\bfseries\upshape}
\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\sffamily\bfseries}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Section}
\newpage
Lorem ipsum
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Or with package `\textls*` provided by package `microtype`:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[
  paper = a4,
  twoside = false,
  numbers = noenddot,  
  parskip = half,
  listof = flat,
  listof = entryprefix,
  chapterprefix = true,
  listof = nochaptergap
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% <- added
\usepackage{microtype}% <- added

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  innerskip=0pt,% skip between chapter prefix and chapter title
  prefixfont=\LARGE% font of chapter prefix
]{chapter}
\renewcommand*\raggedchapter{\raggedleft}% <- chapter alignment
\renewcommand*\chapterlineswithprefixformat[3]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{chapter}
    {#2\textls*[75]{\MakeUppercase{#3}}}% changed definition for chapter
    {#2#3}% original definition
}
\renewcommand*\chaptermarkformat{\thechapter\autodot\enskip}% for header

\renewcommand*{\sectionformat}{%
  \makebox[1.15cm][l]{\thesection\autodot}%
}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionformat}{%
  \makebox[1.15cm][l]{\thesubsection\autodot}%
}  

% ============================================
% HEADER & FOOTER
% ============================================
\usepackage[
  automark,
  markcase=upper% <- uppercase for left and right marks
]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead{\headmark}% <- changed
\ofoot*{\pagemark}
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\sffamily\bfseries\upshape\textls*[75]}% \textls must be the last command
\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\sffamily\bfseries}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Section}
\newpage
Lorem ipsum
\end{document}
```

But note this remark from the KOMA-Script documentation:

> Beyond that, typographers agree that whenever you set whole words or phrases in capital
>   letters, additional spacing is absolutely necessary. However, adding a fixed spacing between all
>   letters is not an adequate solution. Different pairs of letters require different spaces between
>   them. Additionally, some letters already create gaps in the text that must be taken into
>   account. Packages like ulem or soul can scarcely achieve this, nor can \MakeUppercase. The
>   automatic letter spacing using the microtype package is in this respect only an approximate
>   solution, because it does not take into account the concrete, font-dependent glyphs. Because
>   typesetting all-capital text is expert work and almost always requires manual adjustment,
>   ordinary users are recommended avoid using it, or to use it only sparingly and not in such an
>   exposed place as the running head

Comment: Thank you for your detailed execution. However, when I use your solution in my full work, it results to italic page numbering and I don't now exactly why.

Comment: @D5E See my updated answer. I have replaced `\setkomafont{pagenumber}{...}` by `\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{...}`. Now the resulting font settings for `pagenumber` are `\normalfont\normalcolor\sffamily\bfseries`.

Comment: As always you're outsmarting me in KOMA :) Very good answer! I should have quoted scrguien as well.

Comment: BTW: Is there a smart alternative for XeTeX-User since microtype does not support letter spacing with this compiler.

Comment: If the font was selected by a `fontspec` command you can use `\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=20}` in `{#2{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=20}\MakeUppercase{#3}}}` and `\setkomafont{pagehead}{\sffamily\bfseries\upshape\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=20}}`. See the `fontspec` documentation and adjust the value to your needs.

Answer (score 2):

I think the following comes pretty close to your images. Note that redefining `\chapterlinesformat` doesn't do anything as `\chapterlineswithprefixformat` is used if you use `chapterprefix=true`. I hope everything is commented, feel free to ask if you don't understand something.

```
\documentclass[
     paper = a4,
     twoside = false,
     numbers = noenddot,  
     parskip = half,
     listof = flat,
     listof = entryprefix,
     chapterprefix = true,
     listof = nochaptergap]{scrreprt}

% reduce vertical space between prefix and chapter title
\renewcommand\chapterheadmidvskip{\par\nobreak\smallskip}

% set font of the prefix
\setkomafont{chapterprefix}{\bfseries\LARGE}

% uppercasing of chapter title and raggedleft
\renewcommand\chapterlineswithprefixformat[3]
  {%
    \raggedleft
    #2\MakeUppercase{#3}%
  }

\renewcommand*{\sectionformat}{%
  \makebox[1.15cm][l]{\thesection\autodot}%
}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionformat}{%
  \makebox[1.15cm][l]{\thesubsection\autodot}%
}

% ============================================
% HEADER & FOOTER
% ============================================
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead{\MakeUppercase{\headmark}} %Chapter name in header
\ofoot*{\pagemark} %Page number
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\sffamily\bfseries\upshape}
\setkomafont{pagenumber}{\sffamily\bfseries\upshape}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% patch the command which sets the header content to use
% \myheadchaptermarkformat instead of \chaptermarkformat
\patchcmd\chaptermark{chaptermarkformat}{myheadchaptermarkformat}{}{}% patching

% define \myheadchaptermarkformat to only include the number, not the prefix
\newcommand\myheadchaptermarkformat{\thechapter\autodot\enskip}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Section}
\newpage
Lorem ipsum
\end{document}
```

Output of the chapter:

[image]

Output of the page head:

[image]

The following adds `soul`'s `\so` macro to the chapter name in the heading and in the header. It does so in a hacky way, I don't recommend it and don't know how stable the below code is, it works for the MWE, but I don't guarantee it to work.

```
\documentclass[
     paper = a4,
     twoside = false,
     numbers = noenddot,  
     parskip = half,
     listof = flat,
     listof = entryprefix,
     chapterprefix = true,
     listof = nochaptergap]{scrreprt}

% reduce vertical space between prefix and chapter title
\renewcommand\chapterheadmidvskip{\par\nobreak\smallskip}

\usepackage{soul}
% set font of the prefix
\setkomafont{chapterprefix}{\bfseries\LARGE}

% uppercasing of chapter title and raggedleft
\renewcommand\chapterlineswithprefixformat[3]
  {%
    \raggedleft
    #2\mychapterformatter{#3}%
  }
\makeatletter
\newcommand\mychapterformatter[1]
  {%
    \begingroup
    \let\interlinepenalty@original\interlinepenalty
    \let\interlinepenalty\my@interlinepenalty
    #1%
    \endgroup
  }
\newcommand\my@interlinepenalty{}
\long\def\my@interlinepenalty\@M#1\@@par%
  {%
    \interlinepenalty@original\@M
    \MakeUppercase{\so{#1}}%
    \@@par
  }
\makeatother

\renewcommand*{\sectionformat}{%
  \makebox[1.15cm][l]{\thesection\autodot}%
}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionformat}{%
  \makebox[1.15cm][l]{\thesubsection\autodot}%
}

% ============================================
% HEADER & FOOTER
% ============================================
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead{\MakeUppercase{\headmark}} %Chapter name in header
\ofoot*{\pagemark} %Page number
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\sffamily\bfseries\upshape}
\setkomafont{pagenumber}{\sffamily\bfseries\upshape}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% patch the command which sets the header content to use
% \myheadchaptermarkformat instead of \chaptermarkformat
\patchcmd\chaptermark{chaptermarkformat}{myheadchaptermarkformat}{}{}% patching
\patchcmd\chaptermark{#1}{\so{#1}}{}{}

% define \myheadchaptermarkformat to only include the number, not the prefix
\newcommand\myheadchaptermarkformat{\thechapter\autodot\enskip\enskip}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Section}
\newpage
\MakeUppercase{\so{Lorem ipsum}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Really awesome, that's exactly what I was looking for! 
I am not sure if I should open a new question, but can I include somehow let­terspac­ing to the uppercase part of the header and chapter name? I tested soul-package several times, but without any sucess. Just tell me, if I should open a new question for this ...

Comment: @D5E don't add letter spacing. That is a remnant of the past when people were using typewriters and this was the easiest way to emphasize stuff. To be clear: I don't like upper casing stuff and consider it typographical bad practice, but letter spacing might be too much. Perhaps I'll look at it later.